# Persist activity not to go to MAIN

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

when I start activity with following code.

```
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, New1Activity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivityForResult(intent, StaticValue.REQUEST_CODE_MENU_01);
```

after `New1Activity` activity showed up, open another package app such as Facebook app and then go back (by multitasking switch or back button) to my app.
In this scenario, I expected `New1` activity will be given but MainActivity is shown.

In addition, AndroidManifest.xml is as below.

```
        <activity
            android:name="mypackage.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".New1Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            />
```

I noted `noHistory` and `singleTop` to each activity because of my app performance management.

How can I persist my activity status whenever I go back from other app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my stupid.

I removed `noHistory="true"` and it works. (Let say RTFM. LOL)

below is quoted from [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html),

> android:noHistory
>       Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".
>       A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.
>       This attribute was introduced in API Level 3.